# What is application/vnd.adobe.photoshop file format?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format

I am working on a file in Photoshop but I do not know which kind of format the file is. It is the first time I see 'application/vnd.adobe.photoshop' under **File->File Info...->Descripton**

[image]

The information on internet is not clear about it.

Comment: Hi viery, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's a file created in photoshop, most likely `.psd`.

I would try using open as and trying out diffrent programs if it won't open in photoshop. You could also try using a converter if you don't have anything to open it.

Comment: That's it! I made the test right now, and yes, it is a file which was created inside a psd file (let's say) before being exported to another format.  Thank you:)

Comment: Good you found the problem, it was a bit of an odd one

Answer (score 1):

This is called a MIME type.

"application/vnd.adobe.photoshop" means the file is: an application; vendor is adobe; application name is photoshop.

Normally when I see "format" I think it is telling me that the *file itself* is of that type (which would mean your screencap is photoshop), **but** depending on the context, it may be telling me that what is listed is *the required program to open or view the file*, in which case your screencap is of an image file which Photoshop has announced to/registered with the OS as being the default viewer.

If it is not a PSD, it is likely a TIF, JPG, or PNG. You might try "open as".

(note that a PSD file would normally be '**image**/vnd.adobe.photoshop')